# change the order of nested list

Tags: css, flexbox

hi and thanks for checking.

i have a list, that has multiple nestings. i'd like to change the order of these two lists and i wonder if this is possible with only css?

- List item 1
- List item 2

  - List item 2.1
  - List item 2.2
- List item 3

i'd like to change the order to:

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3
- List item 2.1
- List item 2.2

since the length of the list is dynamic, i can't use absolute positioning or stuff like that.

Comment: why did youtag this with flexbox ? are you using flexbox ? how is your markup ? your css ?

Comment: Hmm, if the list is dynamic why not change it in code rather than css? I have no idea if css could do this, but it's certainly not what it's there for.

Comment: If you are using `flexbox` you could use `order` to move the `li` containing the sublist, you won't be able to move the `li`s to the parent list though. Why do you want to do this? Please share your code showing what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. you must order that data where it is rendered, at client side (javascript) or back side; css is helpless in this case

Comment: On some specific situations css can do that https://jsfiddle.net/m8k1g0vy/

Comment: yes but if there are many sub lists you should write css order for every of them. that's why it is better to order data and then render it

Comment: I never said wich option is better I just argue against your  *No, you cannot.* ... as I point on the comment for specific situations can be used

Answer (score 0):

Its a tricky one, but you can do it in a way by using CSS Flexbox `order` property.

You need to change the properties of `<ul>` and `<li>` elements. Have a look at the code snippet below.

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}

/* Resetting properties of <ul> */
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: disc;
}

/* Applying Flex properties to <ul> */
ul.normal-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* Changing the order of all the <li>s except the <ul> with the class 'nested-list'  */
li.nested-list {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="normal-list">
  <li>List Item 1</li>
  <li>List Item 2</li>
  <li class="nested-list">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item 2.1</li>
      <li>List Item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>List Item 3</li>
  <li class="nested-list">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item 3.1</li>
      <li>List Item 3.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>List Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks! for pointing out the mistake, my bad! I've updated my answer and I think this can do the job quite nicely.